# how to count all values in a particular column in within date range according to date

Tags: mysql, date

I have one table having column :

```
ID| rect_id| vieweed_user_id| view_count|view_date
1 | 1      | 1              | 1         |2017-03-07 10:54:21
2 | 1      | 2              | 1         |2017-03-08 01:00:45
3 | 1      | 3              | 1         |2017-03-08 12:54:12
```

I want to find count for all view_count values according to view_date,for example

```
view_date  | view_count
2017-03-08 |    2
2017-03-07 |    1
```

but my problem is I want to find all counted view_count values between a specified date range for example

> from 2016-03-08 to 2017-03-08

Comment: What did you try so far? After all this is not a free-code but a q & a website.

Comment: to all answering: group by date(view_date) instead of just view_date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this.

```
SELECT view_date, sum(view_count) as total_count FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE view_date >= '2016-03-08' AND view_date <= '2017-03-08' group by view_date
```

Comment: Thanks Dave it works but not what i wanted ,it works when I remove time from date because group by works when view_date is like - 2017-03-08 ,but in my problem view_date is 2017-03-08 01:00:45 , how can i get count when groups are diifer by seconds in time

Comment: @sky Try to use GROUP BY CAST(view_date AS DATE) [Cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) or GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),date_column,112) [Convert](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter between dates and group by date to get the output you need

```
select view_date,sum(view_count) from TABLE_NAME where view_date between ('2016-03-08' and '2017-03-08') group by view_date
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @JayBlanchard thanks for the advice I will try my best to give some explanation.